# Showing what pages citations appear using the harvard style file

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing, harvard-style

I am using the `harvard` package from CTAN to typeset my document. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{harvard}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

How can I add information about what pages my citation appear. Can I do this while using `apsr`relatively easily?

Comment: hyperref's backref? http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=backref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seamus appears to be correct. If you're not using `hyperref`, just add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{backref}
```

(Probably this should go after the `harvard`-related stuff.)

If you are using `hyperref`, then just pass the `pagebackref` option to it somehow; either through package options, or using `\hypersetup`.

The `hyperref` manual specifically states that `harvard` *is* supported (though it doesn't actually say anything about backref there), but it recommends using `natbib` instead as that actually cooperates with `hyperref`.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, with or without hyperref. No backrefs appear.

Comment: It works with natbib though.